# Flight information on past flights

Tags: air-travel

I need to find out the arrival to Miami, USA of TAM Flight #8090, from Brasil on July 17 2015.

Answer (score 4):

[FlightAware](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/TAM8090) should have this data, but you will need to register (free) to see it.

Unregistered users get to see 14 days of history for free, registered users get 4 months for free.  Searches further back in time cost hundreds to thousands of dollars (USD) so don't delay.

Comment: Currently (Nov 2023), FlightAware says that a free account does not get historical info nor departure/arrival info.

Answer (score 1):

Some website provide past flight information but that may cost you some money

[Flighttrader24](http://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/jj8090/)

[Flightware](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/TAM8090)

Answer (score -1):

Details here from Flightaware.
http://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/TAM8090/history/20150716/0230Z/SBGR/KMIA

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE Nick. We usually encourage longer more detailed answered as opposed to link-only. Consider posting a table or a screenshot with the actual results